# How can I make these functions work following OOP Principles?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, oop

I have several functions/methods in a class that are kind of connected. I am building a class that mimics terminal commands and links. However, someone told me this is not proper OOP. How can I separate these methods to work independently. Methods shouldn't call other methods. Correct?

```
class directory:
  #FILES, LINKS AND DIRECTORIES
  current_path = []
  hold_files = [
    'test1.txt', 'test2.py',
    {'/desktop': ['computer.txt','tfile.doc',
      {'/peace':{
        '/pictures': [
        'hello.gif',
        'smile.gif',
        'run.gif'
        ]},
    '/work':[
    'file1.txt',
    'file2.txt'
    ]
      }]
    }
  ]

#recursively delete folder (if dot in)
  def delete(itself):
    #if dictionary, call self, else delete
    del itself
    return


      
  ## HELPER METHODS

  # Join list together to produce new link, basically return the added folder to the link
  def concatenate(self):
      new_link ="".join(current_path)
      return new_link


#strip slashes and place in list 
  def adjust_link(self, paths):
      new_string = ""

      # shorten link, if someone uses cd .., basically go back to previous folder
      if paths == "cd ..":
          current_path.pop()

      #extend link, if someone is cding into another folder, remove /'s and append to separate list 
      elif "cd " in paths:
          paths = paths[3:]
          for slash in paths:
              if slash == "/":
                  current.append(new_string)
                  new_string = ""
              else:
                  new_string+=slash
      # This shouldn't be here as OOP must be separated but this calls the other function to concatenate a new link
      stripped = concatenate()
      return stripped


#returns link
  def link(self, paths):
    address_location = adjust_link(paths)
    return address_location



directory.link("cd desktop/peace")
directory.link("cd pictures")
directory.link("cd ..")
directory.delete()
```

Thank you.

*Also, this is not a refactoring question. I already asked on stack exchange code review and they told me to come here. Code does not work.

Edit 2: why won't "directory.link()" work?

Comment: So, I think you need to start with a smaller example. But in any case, you don't use the `self` parameter in any of your methods, which essentially defeats the purpose of having a class, which is to create objects which encapsulate some form of internal state. Note, you calls to things like `concatenate` won't work. I'm not sure I understand thsi comment either: "This shouldn't be here as OOP must be separated but this calls the other function to concatenate a new link" There's nothing wrong with a method calling another method in the same class

Comment: And just some advice on how to get better traction on a question on here, focus on a single part of your class that you want' to address. I'm still not sure I understand your question, in particular, "However, someone told me this is not proper OOP. How can I separate these methods to work independently. They are not supposed to be nested into each other. Correct?" Well, they aren't nested. Do you mean should a method call another method? Because that's totally fine.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thank you for the feedback. yes I meant to say method calling another method. I thought it was discouraged to do in OOP.

Comment: *...someone told me this is not proper OOP.* People will tell you all kinds of stuff, and most of it is garbage.  If you can't explain WHY a rule exists and WHAT goes wrong when you violate it, then research it farther.  If you can explain, then evaluate it against your experience and decide whether you agree.  Develop your own informed opinions rather than parroting someone else's.

Answer (score 0):

"I have a program here and I want to convert it to OOP" is not usually how it's done:  "I have a problem I want to solve using OOP" is usually the approach.  It looks like you are creating something that will traverse an internal directory structure.  So a skeleton might look like:

```
class DirectoryTraverser:

     def __init__(self, directory_tree):
         self.hold_files = directory_tree
         self.current_path = []

     def... #  all your other functions

# then to use it might look like:

# create a directory traversal object with directory tree

dt = DirectoryTraverser(hold_files)  

dt.link("cd desktop/peace")
dt.link("cd pictures")
dt.link("cd ..")
dt.delete()
```